# SwiftUI: How do I transition gracefully when parent view changes?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a view that starts setup like this.

```
var body: some View {
    switch appState.userFlow {
    case .onboarding:
        Text("Not Yet Implemented")
    case .login:
        LandingPageView()
    case .home:
        HomeScreenView()
    }
}
```

In each of those `userFlow`'s I change the appState utilizing an `@EnvironmentObject` Whenever the object changes its state, the view blinks away and the new one is presented. This looks abrupt and ugly as it stands.

I attempted to do something along the lines of this. Which had no effect. What is the proper way to handle a transition when used in this context?

```
LandingPageView().transition(.opacity)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.transition` needs to be applied to the **container of the views** that you want to switch over, so you'll need to embed your `switch` inside a `Group`, `VStack`, or similar.

Also, you need to have either a `.animation(.default)` on the container, or change `appState.userFlow` inside a `withAnimation {}` block to actually animate the change.

```
enum UserFlow {
    case onboarding
    case login
    case home
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userFlow = UserFlow.home
    var body: some View {
        
        /// container
        Group {
            
            switch userFlow {
            case .onboarding:
                Text("Not Yet Implemented")
            case .login:
                Text("Login page")
            case .home:
                Text("Home page")
            }
            
        }
        .animation(.default) /// also need Animation
        .transition(.opacity)
        
        /// for testing
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                userFlow = .login
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Text "Home page" fades to "Login page"]

Comment: Wow okay, that works really good. the `animation(...)` is required? It makes things look weird in other ways doing it that way. I tried setting it to `.none` but as expected, it didn't work.

Comment: @xTwisteDx what do you mean by makes things look weird? Maybe try doing `withAnimation { appState.userFlow = .login }` instead (sometimes explicit animations are less glitchy)

Comment: doing it `withAnimation {}` worked better than the group option. Much better. It looks gorgeous now, and exactly as I expected. Thank you for the help!